# Share Dialog box disappear when we click on home button and we come back

Tags: android, android-intent

I am sharing some content in my app and I use `Intent.ACTION_SEND` to display system `Share Chooser dialog box`. Now the problem is once this native dialog box of android display and if user press `home` button and when we come back to app it disappear.

Here i can not keep track of using `onResume()` because even if user press back button when dialog window is visible at that time even `onResume()` will be invoked as we will come back to our activity from android share chooser dialog box.

So can some one suggest me some way so that I can display that share dialog box again when we come back to app after we press home button.

Comment: you could use a boolean value to keep track if the Share Chooser dialog is being displayed :P

Comment: Hi carnel i can not use boolean variable because even onResume() will get invoked when user will press back. So i can not differentiate weather user pressed home or user pressed back button to close dilog button.

Answer (score 0):

You could use two boolean variables:

```
boolean isDialogShowing, didPressBackButton;
```

When you bring your dialog up, you set `isDialogShowing = TRUE;` and when you press back button, you set `didPressBackButton = TRUE;` in the overridden method for pressing back.

Then in `onResume()` just check these values, something like:

```
if(isDialogShowing && !didPressBackButton){
    // show the dialog again
}
else{
    isDialogShowing = FALSE;
    didPressBackButton = FALSE;
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. But our activity do not get onBackPressed get called as it is native dialog box. It is not dilog box of our application. And even if we handle onBackPressed(). the another issue is user can share content and come back automatically. At that time user will not able to get onBackPressed() called.